# Matlab: sum each column of an nxN matrix with N>>n

Tags: arrays, matlab, parallel-processing, sum

For an `nxN` matrix with `N`>>`n`, I've noticed that matlab `sum()` is not very efficient. As an example, we may consider:

```
N = 10000000;
T = 30;

c=rand(2,N);
tic;for ii=1:T;d=sum(c);end;toc
tic;for ii=1:T;d=c(1,:)+c(2,:);end;toc

> Elapsed time is 1.250268 seconds.
> Elapsed time is 0.567871 seconds.

c=rand(3,N);
tic;for ii=1:T;d=sum(c);end;toc
tic;for ii=1:T;d=c(1,:)+c(2,:)+c(3,:);end;toc

> Elapsed time is 1.514810 seconds.
> Elapsed time is 0.821631 seconds.

c=rand(4,N);
tic;for ii=1:T;d=sum(c);end;toc
tic;for ii=1:T;d=c(1,:)+c(2,:)+c(3,:)+c(4,:);end;toc

> Elapsed time is 1.519009 seconds.
> Elapsed time is 1.069865 seconds.
```

In all cases, the explicit summation takes less time but we can see that `sum` will eventually win as `n` is increased further.

Why is `sum` not as efficient?

---

In addition, `sum` doesn't seem to benefit from more computation threads. For example,

```
c=rand(10,N);

maxNumCompThreads(2);
tic;for ii=1:T;d=sum(c);end;toc

maxNumCompThreads(1);
tic;for ii=1:T;d=sum(c);end;toc

> Elapsed time is 2.496837 seconds.
> Elapsed time is 2.450345 seconds.
```

I guess this somewhat makes sense as the parallelisation probably kicks in only when `n` is large.

Is there a way to make this calculation benefit from multithreading if `n` remains small (e.g., `n<50`)? Or is there a better strategy?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: My guess is that `sum` contains more overhead from being general purpose. You are optimizing by unrolling your sum loop, whereas the `sum` function itself doesn't have that luxury.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Matlab sum performance on multi-dimensional arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17626367/matlab-sum-performance-on-multi-dimensional-arrays)

Comment: @natan Thanks for your comment but the nature of the two questions is different. Here, the question concerns summation of each column of 2D matrices with many columns but few rows, i.e., what is the fastest way to sum a given `nxN` matrix to get a `1xN` vector for large `N` but small `n`? In the other question, I asked what the best strategy for summing a given `nxN` matrix into an `nX1` vector would be. I hope you will agree that the two questions are not duplicate.